# Can you display an ACF field in a taxonomy relationship field in the admin panel?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a taxonomy for city names. They have an ACF field for the state. But when you are editing a post type with this taxonomy associated with it, you only see the city name in the taxonomy select list. This can be problematic for cities like Portland, where there are at least 2 in the USA. Same for Springfield, etc.

Does anyone know if I can apply some hook to display the ACF field with the title in the admin panel when you are editing a post type?

The image below should illustrate the needs. Basically, I just want it to say Portland, ME instead of just Portland (and likewise for other cities). But I need the name separate in the fields so I can't just name the cities with their states respectively.

Anyone done this before?
[image]

I tried googling and using the extended plugin for ACF but pretty much found results for adding columns in the taxonomy edit screen, which I don't need. It's just in the taxonomy module on the side of a post when you're editing that needs some kind of extra field, or ability to concatenate the title with an ACF field.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Orbital's help, I was able to get this to do what I needed. The is_admin part wasn't working because the list is retrieved by ajax so I had to get a little sneaky. This may not be the most secure way to do it, but the function is harmless so I am not concerned about that. Final code below:

```
if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "wp-json" ) == 1 ) {
    add_filter('get_term', 'change_term_name_at_admin', 10, 2);

    function change_term_name_at_admin($term, $taxonomy) {
        if ($taxonomy == 'markets') {
            $key_field_acf = "markets_" . $term->term_id; 

            $state_name = get_field( 'state', $key_field_acf );

            if ($state_name != "") {
                $new_name = $term->name . ', ' . $state_name;
                $term->name = $new_name;
            }
        }
        return $term;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

We change display format only for Wordpress admin for your_taxonomy_name to "Term name - State name"

```
add_filter('get_term', 'change_term_name_at_admin', 10, 2);

function change_term_name_at_admin($term, $taxonomy) {
    //only for admin, not front
    if( is_admin() ) {


   if ($taxonomy == 'your_taxonomy_name') {

            $key_field_acf = "your_taxonomy_name_" . $term->term_id; 

            $state_name = get_field( 'state_name ', $key_field_acf );

            if ($new_name !="") {
             $new_name = $term->name . ' -' . $state_name;
                $term->name = $new_name;
            }

   }
}
    return $term;
}
```

Change in this line

> if ($taxonomy == 'your_taxonomy_name') {

and in this line

> $key_field_acf = "your_taxonomy_name_" . $term->term_id;

your_taxonomy_name to your cities taxonomy name

Comment: Ooh, its so promising. I think that is supposed to be if($state_name) != '' but none the less, when i die($term->name) it is properly combining them. But it is not affecting the way it's displayed in the lists when choosing a taxonomy. If I echo, it will show for a second, then when the edit form is rendered it goes away and no difference in the list is evident.

Comment: It should be noted that this DOES effectively display the city and state on the taxonomy edit page itself, so it definitely does something there. Just not in the little sidebar box when editing an item with this taxonomy associated

Comment: ... oooh, and it also works when I remove the is_admin part... Well, I think this is enough to run with. I can figure out some other way to make this admin only if need be. I will update my post with the final code and mark this as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Ok got it. With just a few minor edits this was what I needed. Thanks, Orbital! I updated my question with the final code.